# Quantum ESPRESSO "Error in routine do_projwfc (5010): reading projwfc namelist"

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

I'm running a PDOS calculation in QE but the file has an output and has an error.

**Input:**

```
&projwfc
    prefix='pwscf',
    outdir='./tmp'
    filproj='pdoss'
    deltae  =  1,00000e-02
    emax    =  5,00000e+01
    emin    = -5,00000e+01
/
```

**Output:**

```
 Error in routine do_projwfc (5010):
     reading projwfc namelist
```

Comment: You are using `,` as a decimal separator for `DeltaE`, `Emax`, and `Emin`. Try using `.` and also, if possible, use the correct capitalization (though the capitalization should not be an issue I believe, but it's a good practice to stick with the [user manual](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/INPUT_PROJWFC.html#idm26)!)

Comment: And a general remark about QE: whenever you get an error saying `reading ****** namelist`, that most certainly means you have problems in your input file.

Comment: do the above comments help? Are you still actively looking for an answer to this question?

Comment: Yes, they helped, I already got the results I expected.